# Как извлечь столбцы из сложной html-таблицы?

Tags: html, python, pandas, анализ-данных, multi-index

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как получить доступ к столбцам Date.1 и New в таблице.

```
import pandas as pd   
dfs = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:COVID-19_pandemic_data/Russia_medical_cases')  
dfs[0][['Confirmed','Date']][:-2]   # возвращает необходимые строки и четыре столбца, а надо только два
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [pd.IndexSlice](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html):

```
In [37]: idx = pd.IndexSlice

In [38]: dfs[0].loc[:, idx[["Confirmed", "Date"], ["Date", "New"]]]
Out[38]:
        Date   Confirmed
        Date         New
0     31 Jan           1
1     11 Feb           –
2     12 Feb           –
3      2 Mar           1
4      5 Mar           1
..       ...         ...
99    9 June        8595
100  10 June        8404
101    Total  493,657[a]
102     Date         New
103     Date   Confirmed

[104 rows x 2 columns]
```

---

Из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1139666/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%87%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b1%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-html-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b/1139670#comment1971380_1139670):

> А как прочесть значения полей, например, в 99-ой строке? Чтобы
> получить "9 June" и 8595?

```
In [51]: dfs[0].loc[99, idx[["Confirmed", "Date"], ["Date", "New"]]]
Out[51]:
Date       Date    9 June
Confirmed  New       8595
Name: 99, dtype: object
```

Comment: Спасибо. А как прочесть значения полей, например, в 99-ой строке? Чтобы получить "9 June" и 8595.

Comment: Спасибо еще раз. Подскажите, как построить график, чтобы выводились по оси х - значения Date, по y - значения New? Я вызывал .plot(), но получил ошибку "no numeric data to plot".

Comment: @user393475, Лучше задать отдельный вопрос

Comment: [Добавил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1139913)