# Как построить график на основе данных из html-таблицы со сложной структурой?

Tags: python, pandas, графика

Есть таблица

```
import pandas as pd   
dfs = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:COVID-19_pandemic_data/Russia_medical_cases')
```

Надо получить выборку столбцов 'Date.Date.1' и 'Confirmed.New'. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выборку получаю так:

```
data = dfs[0].loc[:99, pd.IndexSlice[["Confirmed", "Date"], ["Date", "New"]]]
```

Надо вывести Date на ось X, а значения New на ось Y.
Пытаюсь вывести данные следующим образом:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
data.plot.line()
```

Но получаю ошибку.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как построить график?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dfs = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:COVID-19_pandemic_data/Russia_medical_cases')

data = dfs[0].loc[:99, pd.IndexSlice[["Confirmed", "Date"], ["Date", "New"]]]

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
X = pd.to_datetime(data["Date"]["Date"]+' 2020')
Y = pd.to_numeric(data["Confirmed"]["New"], errors="coerce").fillna(0)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.plot(X, Y)
```

Вам, однако, надо решить, что делать с отсутствующими данными в столбце New - я пока заменил их на 0. Кроме того, по оси x временная шкала у вас довольно условная, поскольку даты у вас заданы весьма дискретно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPDATE**

После уточнений автора вопроса, предлагаю сделать так:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

dfs = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:COVID-19_pandemic_data/Russia_medical_cases')

data = dfs[0].loc[:99, pd.IndexSlice[["Confirmed", "Date"], ["Date", "New"]]]
data.columns = data.columns.droplevel()

data["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["Date"]+' 2020')
data["New"] = pd.to_numeric(data["New"], errors="coerce")
data.set_index("Date", inplace=True)

idx = pd.date_range(start = data.index.min(), end = data.index.max(), freq="D")
data = data.reindex(idx)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=10))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m-%d'))

ax.scatter(data.index, data["New"])
ax.plot(data.index, data["New"])
ax.grid(True)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо. Я не совсем понял, что не так с датами? Что можно с ними сделать?

Comment: У вас даты идут неравномерными группами - 31 января - 11 февраля - 2 марта - 5 марта. при этом на оси ординат они отображаются через равные промежутки. Если вас это устраивает, то все нормально. Если нет, то, возможно, вам стоит задуматься о задании date_range. Но в этом случае отсутствующих данных будет еще больше, и вам опять нужно решать, что с ними делать.

Comment: Понял. Возможно сделать встроенными средствами plt следующее: выводить сетку, чтобы каждый 10-й день был отмечен вертикальной линией. И чтобы надписи на оси X были только для каждого месяца и без указания года.

Comment: возможно сделать все. но я в третий раз обращаю ваше внимание - у вас есть данные НЕ за каждый день. поэтому вам нужно определиться, какие данные учитывать вместо отсутствующих, или же считать не каждые 10 дней, а каждый 10 зарписей.

Comment: По идее, если отсутствуют даты, то график не должен выводиться. Подскажите, пожалуйста, так возможно сделать?

Comment: Большое спасибо!